# Rails: default value for select not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, simple-form-for

I have this code

```
<%= simple_form_for(@article) do |f| %>
<%= f.select :imp, options_for_select(["",1,1.5,2,2.5,5]), :selected => @article.imp %>
<% end %>
```

When I edit the form I want the previously saved value of the field imp to show as default as selected. I am doing this now but this is not working nor giving any error.

Answer (score 1):

When you edit the form and you want the previously saved value of the field imp to show as default as selected. Please add :include_blank to a field it will have that as the default selected value for a new object. However, when editing a object it will set the select box to whatever has been chosen.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@article) do |f| %>
    <%= f.select :imp, options_for_select(["",1,1.5,2,2.5,5]), :selected => @article.imp .include_blank: true %>
<% end %>
```